# Combine values of arrays that share the same key

Tags: php, arrays

I looked for a while but couldn't find a similar question.

I have an array like this:

```
$array = [
"555" => ['Juan', 'Gomez'],
"555" => ['Foo', 'Bar'],
"556" => ['Test', 'Test']
];
```

I want to combine the values that share the same key, so when I implode it prints something like this:

```
"555" => ['Juan', 'Gomez', 'Foo', 'Bar']
"556" => ['Test', 'Test'];
```

---

It seems the function array_merge_recursive accomplish what I want.
It groups the arrays

```
$array1 = array('"555"' => array('Juan', 'Gomez'));
$array2 = array('"555"' => array('Foo', 'Bar'));
```

Into

```
array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);

Output:

Array
(
    ["555"] => Array
        (
            [0] => Juan
            [1] => Gomez
            [2] => Foo
            [3] => Bar
        )

)
```

However I'm dynamically loading values from a table, so I cannot name each row, that would be insane, is there a way to usa that function with just one array?

I tried

```
$array[] = array('"555"' => array('Juan', 'Gomez'));
$array[] = array('"555"' => array('Foo', 'Bar'));

and array_merge_recursive($array);
```

But it doesn't merge them at all with just one.

Comment: Hello.
Actually when you say "I have an array[...]the values that share the same key," I pretty much think that we have a problem right off the bat because in php you CAN'T have 2 array elements sharing the same key. So right from the beginning, the way your problem is stated is not possible.
In reality, when you add a subsequent element which has the same key as an existing element, the previous element disappears; so your array is actually the following ["555" => ['Foo', 'Bar'],"556" => ['Test', 'Test']]

Comment: I see, what a shame, I need to group values with something in common and I thought about using keys.

Comment: Could we have an real exemple of what you exaclty need, because, what you show here is clearly impossible. Element of your array with same keys will be overwritten by the last same key

Comment: It's very simple, I have mysql table with names of people and a family number, so I want to group people that share the same family number.

Comment: @MaximilianoCorbo Can you give a hint of your table schema or just the sql query you intend to make ? Because to me it looks like something that could be achieved just using sql GROUP BY and/or GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: Yes show the table structure, it is much easier to do in the query and when fetching.

Comment: The table is like this: Family | Name | Lastname.
I want to print a list of names ordered and grouped by family.
Like so:
555. Juan Gomez, Foo Bar.
556. Test Test.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "have an array like this", since array keys are unique.

So you would need to step back to where you create that array and check there if that key already exists or not, if it exists, merge the values.

```
while ($doStuff) {

  // $myKey = '555';


  // Create an empty array for that key
  if (!isset($myArray[$myKey])) {
    $myArray[$myKey] = [];
  }

  // $myListOfNames = ['Juan', 'Gomez']
  // Merge the names with the array for that key
  $myArray[$myKey] = array_merge($myArray[$myKey], $myListOfNames);

  // Or if you just want to add a single value to the list
  $myArray[$myKey][] = $myName;
  

}
```